# How to get value from a Mono subscribe call

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have something like this:

```
mono.subscribe(val -> doSomething(val));
```

`doSomething` returns an integer. I would get and return that integer, or a `Mono<int>`. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return `Mono<Integer>` you can do the following:

```java
Mono<Integer> result = mono.map(value -> doSomething(value));
```

But remember that in Reactor, nothing happens until subscribe, so don't forget to subscribe:

```java
result.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If you want to get an integer out of mono, then you can replace subscribe with block, but pay attention that this is a blocking operation:

```java
Integer result = mono.map(App2::doSomething).block();
```